# Finding the sum $\sum_{q=0}^{2016}\sqrt{2}^{\binom{q+3}{3}}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

> Find the sum
>   $\displaystyle{\quad%
> \sum_{q = 0}^{2016}\left(\,\sqrt{\, 2\, }\,\right)^{\binom{\displaystyle{q + 3}}{\displaystyle{3}}}}
> $.

This sum was encountered while solving a problem of combinatorics. I"ve never seen anything like this before so I'd be grateful if any hints or partial solutions to this problem are given.

Note: I am trying to find the number of  polynomials with degree $q\leq 2016$ and coefficients $1$ or $0$ such that the sum of coefficients is always an odd number. Does the above-written sum solve the problem ?.

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? Do you have a reason to expect there to be a nicer form than the one you wrote?

Comment: Well, a numerical answer would work for me.

Comment: Honestly, I wish for an analytical closed-form solution.

Comment: It's going to be $\sqrt2^{\binom{2019}3}$ plus a relatively negligible term; that largest term is correct to over 300,000 significant figures.

Comment: @Babak even I would like that, but I am kind of short on time.

Comment: Aren't we all...

Comment: What an interesting looking sum. It's not often one comes across the summation where the power is a binomial coefficient.

Comment: @martycohen too good!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the sum you've written is not helpful for the problem.

First of all, note that there is this useful identity for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$ that $$\sum_{k=0\\\mathrm{even}}^n\binom nk=\sum_{k=1\\\mathrm{odd}}^n\binom nk=2^{n-1}$$
which you can easily prove by expanding $(1+x)^n$ for both $x=-1$ and $x=1$ and grouping even/odd parts.

Now, assume $q$ is given. We're looking for polynomials of degree $q$ with coefficients being $1$ or $0$, and their sum being an odd number. Obviously, the coefficient of the largest degree ($x^q$) has to be $1$ which means the sum of the remaining $q$ coefficients must be even. In other words, we have to choose an even number of coefficients and set them to $1$, and others to $0$. The number of ways we can do this is equal to the number of ways we can choose an even number of the remaining $q$ coefficients, i.e., $$n_q=\sum_{k=0\\\mathrm{even}}^q\binom qk=2^{q-1}$$

Since you want all degrees $q\leq2016$, you have to add up these as (note that I've excluded the case $q=0$ from the summation and added it manually) $$n=1+\sum_{q=1}^{2016}2^{q-1}$$ which equals \begin{aligned}n&=1+2^{2016}-1\\&=2^{2016}\end{aligned}

You can get this answer in a shorter way by using the *Robert Israel*'s answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't solve that problem.

That problem (not the sum, the one about polynomials) is equivalent to counting  ${\bf x} \in \{0,1\}^{2017}$ such that $\sum_i x_i$ is odd.  Hint: what happens when you flip $x_1$?