# If the degree of a polynomial is $m$ then find the number of coefficients.

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Suppose we are given with a polynomial $M(x,y,z)$ which has degree $m$ then how many coefficients does it have. I am guessing that since $M$ assumes the form:$$\sum c_kx^iy^jz^k$$ 
then since each variable can have powers ranging from $0$ to $m$ we can conclude that the number of coefficients is $(m+1)^3.$ This seems consistent with the fact that if the polynomial is univariate then the number of coefficients should be $(m+1)^1$ which is indeed true. Is this reasoning true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be fine if you defined the degree of a multivariate polynomial as the maximum of its degrees with respect to each of the indeterminates.  However, it is more usual to consider the "total degree", so that $x^i y^j z^k$ has total degree $i+j+k$.  If the total degree is $m$, the maximum number of terms is the number of triples $(i,j,k)$ of nonnegative integers with $i+j+k \le m$.

Comment: Then the number of coefficients should be $\binom{m+2}{2}$, right?

Comment: No, ${m+3 \choose 3}$.

Comment: Alright, thank you! By the way, you might be interested in this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2013955/finding-the-sum-sum-q-02016-sqrt2-binomq33